# mysql replication adding slaves at later stage

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to setup mysql replication environment my main question is related to adding slaves later, Is it possible to add more slaves at later stage just use one or to initially. what are the issues or drawbacks of the same .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add slaves in the later stages of implementation. some of the issues and solutions are described in this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto-additionalslaves.html)